# How to "\DoNotIndex" an environment?

Tags: makeindex, dtx, literate-programming

I'm writing a dtx file for a class I created. I'm using `\EnableCrossrefs`, but I have the `minted` environment indexed. `\DoNotIndex{minted}` does not work.

How do I tell `makeindex` to not index a specific environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, if I read the source code of `doc` package correctly, `\DoNotIndex` only applies to the parsing logic of `doc` package to decide whether or not to invoke `\index` command on control sequences found while parsing the content of the `macrocode` environment.

It has nothing to do with the `makeindex` tool (which always processes all the entries in the index file), you need to make sure that the index is not written to the index file in the first place by e.g. patching commands.

The parsing logic itself does not check for environments in the code inside `macrocode` environment at all.

Commands like `\DescribeEnv{...}` and `\begin{environment}{...}` etc. calls `\SpecialEnvIndex` which always write to the index file. So simply don't use `\DescribeEnv` or `\begin{environment}` on environments that are not provided by your package.

Nevertheless, if you insist, it's possible to patch the commands to check the exclude list. This is an example of modifying `\DescribeEnv` definition to create `\DescribeEnvNoIndex`:

```
\iffalse   % original definitions:
\def\DescribeEnv{\leavevmode\@bsphack\begingroup\MakePrivateLetters
 \Describe@Env}
\def\Describe@Env#1{\endgroup
              \marginpar{\raggedleft\PrintDescribeEnv{#1}}%
              \SpecialEnvIndex{#1}\@esphack\ignorespaces}
\fi


\def\DescribeEnvNoIndex{\leavevmode\@bsphack\begingroup\MakePrivateLetters
 \Describe@EnvNoIndex}
\def\Describe@EnvNoIndex#1{\endgroup
              \marginpar{\raggedleft\PrintDescribeEnv{#1}}%
              \@esphack\ignorespaces}
```

or pull the definition from the macro definition itself (this way there's no "internal commands" being used)

```
\marginpar{\raggedleft\PrintDescribeEnv{dummyEnvb}}
```

or patch `\DescribeEnv` to check if the name is excluded:

```
\def\DescribeEnv{\leavevmode\@bsphack\begingroup\MakePrivateLetters
 \Describe@Env}
\def\Describe@Env#1{\endgroup
              \marginpar{\raggedleft\PrintDescribeEnv{#1}}%
              \def\macro@namepart{#1}\ifnot@excluded\SpecialEnvIndex{#1}\fi
              \@esphack\ignorespaces}
```

Note that you need to include the backslash (e.g. `\DoNotIndex{\dummyEnvb}`) in this implementation because `\ifnot@excluded` is hard coded to check the backslash.